# Trying to get Cherokee Alphabet to show up in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

So i'm working on this app to help teach the Cherokee language. I've got the characters showing up in the virtual phone while building it. But when I go to run it on the physical phone it just shows boxes. I've tried changing the encoding, perhaps I did something wrong. Any advice?

(Also first time on stack overflow, sorry if I've not provided enough details or phrased everything appropriately, I figure i'll learn as I go.)

Thanks again for any/all help.

Answer (score 0):

This does sound like there is an issue with the font you use in the application on your phone. Make sure your virtual phone and physical phone use the same font.

Welcome to the forum!